# how to Manage the sharepoint (moss 2007) site view as per the user role

Tags: permissions, view, sharepoint-2007

I have the sharepoint site (MOSS2007 site) . It has 3 users. Admin as Administrator of site. user1 and user2 are the user having the Contribute and view. also I have 3 Lists and 2 document libraries. Out of these 2 list and 1 document library should be view on site when user1 and user2 logged in. where as Admin should have full control. how to gain this. what settings i have to do in my site ?

In short I want to manage the site view (webparts,list and document libraries as per the Logged in user's permissions)

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Audience Targeting on individual webparts on the home page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms573802(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks Madhur, so is there any settings o administration level of site , so that a perticular list will visible only for administrator not for user1,user2 ?

Comment: There is no setting for visiblity, but if user doesn't have permission at all, he will not see the list due to security trimming.

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to touch to programming as far as things happening in scope of in built functionality. Now can we do this : If there is list in site. say user1 is logged in so he should no see the list item associates with the user2, and viceversa . but when admin logged in he can see list items associates with both users. Can this possible, how?